# What can be first parameter in Facebook::api method?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, path, facebook-php-sdk

`Facebook::api` method has [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) as follows:

First parameter is path: 
Description of parameter: 
The Graph API path for the request, e.g. "/me" for the logged in user's profile.

Following documentation, there is an example how `$path` argument can look like:

```php
 $ret = $facebook->api( array(
                     'method' => 'fql.query',
                     'query' => 'SELECT . . . ',
                 ));
```

I cannot find any documentation, that `$path` can be an array and what keys can the array contain. There is just this example in documentation page. Am I missing something? Where can I find list of all possible keys and all possible values the `$path` array can contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$path` is not an array, its a string- basically a Graph API path for the request. There's no such list of the $path, you just search for whatever you are wishing to. For eg:

```
user info: "\me"
user albums: "\me\albums"
user's friends: "\me\friends"
friend's info: "\FRIEND_ID"
```

and so on ..

Comment: so why is in example the first argument of api function array with two keys 'method' and 'query'?

Comment: That's if you use `fql`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I marked your answr useful, but it is not complete answer on my question. You say, array is "if you use fql". So it is true that it can be aray. What else the path can be? What keys can have this array. Is there any other IF, when it can be array too or fql is the only exception? Why this is not on documentation page (on link from question).

Comment: See $path has nothing to do with `fql`. There are 2 different thing: `Graph API Methods` and `FQL Queries` and link differentiates both clearly. Why are you considering $path as an array, its mentioned nowhere- its the Graph API path. The keys (for fql function) can be `method` `query` `params`. So, without creating the confusion keep in mind that there are 2 methods for api call : `Graph API`: `$ret = $facebook->api($path, $method, $params);` and `FQL queries`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ret = $facebook->api("me","feed","message"=>"Hello i am posting on your wall");
```

Where "me" is the path which is the fb_id of the user on whose timeline you want to post something,"feed" is the action and "message" is the content you want to post.

Maybe [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) link can help you.

Comment: I don't want to post on the wall. I would like to have whole documenttion of api method, not an example. "me" is just an example, how to set first parameter $path.